# Регулярное выражение в php поиск всех совпадений в строке

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть строка, это всегда строка с тегами `proxy, core, error, get`, но всегда имеющая разный порядок написания тегов. После тега всегда идет двоеточие, затем комментарий тега, все выглядит примерно так:

> Core:init Proxy: Attemps is ended. Error: Proxy connect timeout Error: core unknown Core:error parse line

С помощью регулярного выражения я пытаюсь поймать все совпадения, они должны выглядеть так:

```
Core:init 
Proxy: Attemps is ended. 
Error: Proxy connect timeout 
Error:core unknown 
Core:error parse line
...
```

Используя следующую регулярное выражение `(?>(?:core|proxy|error|get)\:(.+?)(?=(core|proxy|error|get)\:))` я получаю почти правильный результат, а точнее все совпадения без последнего вхождения. Я перепробовал массу вариантов написания регулярок и все они работают не правильно. Как мне заставить регулярное выражение ловить все совпадения в строке?

Пример: https://regex101.com/r/V97LNk/1

Еще варианты которые я пробовал: https://regex101.com/r/WzZ9A3/1 и https://regex101.com/r/xCJHOF/1

Так же я играл с `PREG_SET_ORDER` и `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` в функции `preg_match_all` однако это не дало значимых изменений.

Comment: `(?:core|proxy|error|get):\s*\K.+?(?=\s*(?:core|proxy|error|get):|\z)` (https://regex101.com/r/V97LNk/2) сойдёт?

Comment: `(?>(?:core|proxy|error|get)\:(.+?)(?=(core|proxy|error|get)\:|$))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, уберите всё лишнее: атомарная группировка и экранирование перед двоеточиями не нужны.

Во-вторых, основная проблема — отсутствие альтернативы с концом строки: блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?=(core|proxy|error|get):)` требует наличия `core`, `proxy`, `error` или `get`, за которыми следует символ `:`, но если там конец строки, совпадения не будет.

Конец строки можно найти с помощью `$` или `\z` (после этого не может быть ничего, даже символа LF в самом конце строки).

Используйте один из двух шаблонов:

```
(?:core|proxy|error|get):(.+?)(?=(core|proxy|error|get):|$)
(?:core|proxy|error|get):(.+?)(?=(core|proxy|error|get):|\z)
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/V97LNk/3).

Возможно, вам больше подойдёт

```
(core|proxy|error|get):\s*\K.+?(?=\s*(?1):|\z)
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/V97LNk/5).

**Подробности**

- `(core|proxy|error|get)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: одно из указанных слов
- `:` - двоеточие
- `\s*` - ноль и более пробельных символов
- `\K` - оператор, очищающий буфер текущего совпадения (весь текст, найденный до сих пор, удаляется из этого буфера)
- `.+?` - один  и более символов, отличных от перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `(?=\s*(?1):|\z)` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, который требует наличия ноля и более пробельных символов (`\s*`), последовательности шаблонов, заданных в подмаске №1 (`(?1)`), а затем `:`, или `|` конец строки `\z` (можно использовать `$` тоже).

Comment: Последний вариант работает хорошо. Можно ли в целом упростить и написать так `(core|proxy|error|get):\s*\K.+?(?=\s*(?:\1):|\z)` ?

Comment: @ВикторКузнецов Можно так: `(core|proxy|error|get):\s*\K.+?(?=\s*(?1):|\z)` ([пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/V97LNk/4)). `(?1)` — рекурсивный шаблон, повторяющий шаблоны захватывающей подмаски №1.

Comment: Супер, так и оставляем. Спасибо огромное :) про \K увидел в первые и не совсем понял что это. Буду изучать.

Comment: @ВикторКузнецов Я добавил объяснение шаблона.